# How does next.js determine the value of NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, localhost

I am not setting any environment variable for `NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL`. However, on running the application locally and using a `.env.local` file, I see the `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL` is set to `localhost:3000`

I have tried looking for it in the next cli source code, but I am not able to find where it's being set

Comment: That is definitely not set by Next.js. If you're sure it doesn't come from your codebase (a quick search should confirm it), then look in the packages that the app is using.